# Magento 2 hidden products

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, orders, product-attribute

My scenario is to give a bag if a customer purchases a product. But customer will not be known only warehouse workers will be insisted to give bag for the product. I'm having a order export functionality to export daily orders to warehouse. In that sheet I have to show bag as new line to appropriate product. I have to add a product to order which should not show in cart or orders and anywhere. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

when you are exporting your order you can add bags or extra stuff '

Means when you click on export order button ] just add extra items there on basic of the order details.

By this only warehouse worker will get the export report with extra details like bag for product and customer will be unaware and also it can't be seen in order or anywhere